# regarding tabs in html

Tags: html

while movin the mouse near the parent tab it should show the all menus under that tab how can we do this in html

Comment: http://message.uk.com/dropdown-menus-no-thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in HTML. You must use for it JavaScript and CSS (eg. jQuery or other AJAX library is good for it).

Answer (score 1):

Nested lists, ie the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, together with css `:hover` properties should be able to achieve this, but experience tells me to use one of the many easier options out there, with a dash of JS.

A good start is the [suckerfish family](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns) - this gives you an idea of where to start, and is cross browser, and then move on to [son of suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/).

There are many many ways to do this, but I've found these the simplest and most adaptable.